# Getting error when try to add new row access policy in Snowflake

Tags: sql, security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an issue with covering tables/views by row access policies (RAP) in Snowflake.
We have several main tables in the database that all the others refer to (PK -> FK relations).

We've created RAP for main tables and trying add RAP to others tables, but get error during RAP creating:

```
SQL compilation error: Policy body contains a UDF or Select statement that refers to a Table attached to another Policy.
```

I understand the reason of error - Snowflake doesn't support creating nested RAP, but maybe someone have any workaround for such cases.
I will be grateful for any help.

Sample code for re-produce provided below:

```
create table t_1(
    pk_id int,
    value_t_1 string
);

create table t_2(
    pk_id int,
    fk_id int,
    value_t_2 string
);

insert into t_1(pk_id, value_t_1) values (1, 'val 1');
insert into t_1(pk_id, value_t_1) values (2, 'val 2');
insert into t_1(pk_id, value_t_1) values (3, 'val 3');

insert into t_2(pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) values (1, 1, 'val 1 1');
insert into t_2(pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) values (2, 1, 'val 2 1');
insert into t_2(pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) values (3, 2, 'val 3 2');
insert into t_2(pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) values (4, 2, 'val 4 2');
insert into t_2(pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) values (5, 2, 'val 5 2');

-- dummy RAP just for example. In real world we have some business logic inside.
CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY IF NOT EXISTS t_1_row_access_policy AS (pk_id int) RETURNS BOOLEAN -> TRUE;
ALTER table t_1 ADD ROW ACCESS POLICY t_1_row_access_policy ON (pk_id);

select * from t_1;

-- getting error:
CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY IF NOT EXISTS t_2_row_access_policy AS (fk_id int)
RETURNS BOOLEAN ->
    EXISTS (
        select *
        from t_1
        where t_1.pk_id = fk_id
        )
    ;
```

Comment: Can you explain what the business process/logic is that you are trying to implement with these nested RAPs?

Comment: @NickW, RAPs for main tables - filtering by users (only these tables have user_name columns), RAPs for other tables - join to main tables by FK for applying filtering by users.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting a RAP on the second table, you could create a view e.g.

```
create view vw_t_2 (pk_id, fk_id, value_t_2) as 
select t2.*
from t_2 t2
inner join t_1 t1
on t1.pk_id = t2.fk_id
```

;